# MATE panel keyboard LED not showing

Tags: 20.04, mate

20.04 updated.

In the MATE tweak dialog for Panel settings, I have selected 'Enable Keyboard LED'. I expect to see an icon showing the status of NumLock and Caps Lock but I'm not seeing it.

I have three panels : top,bottom, right. The icon appears in none of them.

Journal shows :

```
 wnck-applet[3103]: Failed to get pattern 14791762,0,1030
```

But I think this is unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Enable keyboard LED* option should show the corresponding applet on the MATE Panel with the Indicator applet added:

[image: Keyboard LED]

If it is not shown, try to toggle with:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general duplicate-leds false
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.general duplicate-leds true
```

and/or reinstall corresponding packages with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4
```

The message about *wnck* is not related to the discussed problem, it is related to Workspace Switcher applet.